# How do I configure a CIFS only NetApp filer for ssh public-private key access?

Tags: ssh, cifs, netapp

I've a NetApp filer that's running exclusively CIFS. (/vol/vol0 is CIFS exported)
Account logins via ssh are possible as `DOMAIN\username`, but we're having difficulty with configuring ssh public-private key pairs.

Normally we'd create an `authorized_keys` file in order to allow access, but can't figure out the account mapping. (Filer login as `DOMAIN\username` works, but *not* as just `username`)

How do we go about setting this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that you're missing is that the filer is being very literal in terms of finding an `authorized_keys` file. Specifically it looks in:

`/etc/sshd/username/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The problem here is - you need to set `username` to `DOMAIN\username` which isn't a valid windows filename. (Creating a directory called `.ssh` is problematic too) You can do this from the box, using `mv` though.

1. Log in to your linux box.
2. Generate a public-private key pair with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
3. open the 'vol0' cifs export `\\filername\c$` from a windows host.
4. Create a directory `etc/sshd/<username>/ssh`
5. Create a file in this directory `authorized_keys`
6. paste into this file the contents of `id_rsa.pub` from your linux box. (Can also use PuTTY keys).
7. Log into the filer via ssh (you'll still need your password)
8. `mv /etc/sshd/<username>/ssh /etc/sshd/<username>/.ssh`
9. `mv /etc/sshd/<username> /etc/sshd/<DOMAIN\username>`
10. This will look like `DOMAIN~1` or similar on your Windows box, because it's not a valid filename.
11. `priv set -q advanced; ls /etc/sshd` will show you it correctly.
12. log out
13. Add to your linux box `.ssh/config`:

    ```
    Host *
        User DOMAIN\username
    ```
14. Verify you can now ssh using `ssh filername version`. No password should be requested.

You can troubleshoot be looking in `/vol0/etc/log/auditlog`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is:

```
secureadmin setup ssh
```

This creates \filer\etc$\sshd for you.

Comment: It does, but it doesn't create the per-user subdirectories - which is the problem I've got. We _have_ to use individual accounts, because policy.